# how to change the title of Title Bar on the left up corner of the screen with code

Tags: android

I create a android project with Bottom Navigation  Activity template, then I get three default fragment,

in the method: onCreateView of  DashboardFragment ,i added  getActivity().setTitle("Important");

but the titile (on the left up corner of the screen)  is still "Dashboard",it didn't change to "Important" why?
I want to change the title with code ,I want to change it when running the app,not just config it in the mobile_navigation.xml

thanks.

here is mobile_navigation.xml
here is   mobile_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.example.testfragmentjump.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.example.testfragmentjump.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:name="com.example.testfragmentjump.ui.notifications.NotificationsFragment"
        android:laabel="@string/title_notifications"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notifications" />
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove the title of Dashboard Fragment to check where it is in XML or Code class,then by code your able to change the title as per your selection of fragment!

Comment: It is here ,it is the android:label: in mobile_navigation.xml,  I can change the title by change the xml,  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.example.testfragmentjump.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

Comment: So Now it's changing or not.?

Comment: If I change the android:label="@string/title_dashboard" to   "Important"  the title is changed ,but I want to change it with code, because I want to change it when user press a button , so I can't change the xml file.

Comment: getActivity().setTitle("your name"); this is the code now you check where you get fragment onlick to replace fragments based on case which fragment is selected from where you add this code and manage name based on fragment selection!

Comment: but because I used the Bottom Navigation Activity template (which is in android studio ),      I can't find which code  is triggered  when I change (select) the fragment,

Comment: I add the file:mobile_navigation.xml on my topic  , I   think how to get navigation_dashboard ,then set the android:label, or other way to change the title with code .